# Nodejs non-blocking and Event Emitter. Refresh URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

fist of all im not shure if the following is a non-blocking problem?

im getting started with https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter

currently i try to read all files out of a folder and later process all files...

i used EventEmitter to kind of manage the workflow.

i want to clear all arrays if the URL is refeshed or loaded new, but somehow if i reaload the URL there seems to be something inside the arrays which cases multiple outputs of the same data?

at the moment i just would be happy to have a correct console.log output.

```
/**
 * GET /
 * Home page.
 */
var fs = require('fs');
//XML
var jsxml = require("node-jsxml");
var Namespace = jsxml.Namespace,
    QName = jsxml.QName,
    XML = jsxml.XML,
    XMLList = jsxml.XMLList;

//EventEmitter    
var EventEmitter=require('events').EventEmitter;
var dateinamenEE=new EventEmitter();
var dateiinhaltEE=new EventEmitter();
var dateinamen = [];
var dateiinhalt = [];


exports.index = function(req, res) {
    fs.readdir('./data', function (err, files) { 
        if (!err) {
            files.forEach(function(value) {
                dateinamen.push(value);
            });
            dateinamenEE.emit('dateinamen_ready');
        } else {
            throw err; 
        }
    });

    dateinamenEE.on('dateinamen_ready',function(){
        dateinamen.forEach(function(value) {
            var buf = fs.readFileSync('./data/'+value, "utf8");
            var xml = new XML(buf);
            var list = xml.descendants("suggestion");
            var ergebnis = "";
            var basiswort = "";
            var buchstabe = "";
            var obj = null; 
            list.each(function(item, index){
                ergebnis = item.attribute('data').toString()
                //basiswort = value.replace("%2B", " ");
                //basiswort = basiswort.replace(".xml", "");
                //var pieces = buchstabe.split(" ");


                obj = {k: basiswort, b: buchstabe, e: ergebnis};
                dateiinhalt.push(obj);
            });
        });
        dateiinhaltEE.emit('dateiinhalt_ready');
    });

    dateiinhaltEE.on('dateiinhalt_ready',function(){
        //console.log(dateiinhalt);
        console.log("dateinamen:" + dateinamen.length);
        console.log("dateiinhalt:" + dateiinhalt.length);
    });

    res.render('home', {
        title: 'Home'
    });
};
```

If if log the length of the 2 arrays the output on the second reload shows. First time loading the url:

```
Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode
dateinamen:2
dateiinhalt:20
```

Second time / refreshing the url:

```
GET / 200 898.198 ms - -
GET /fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0 304 12.991 ms - -
GET /favicon.ico 200 4.516 ms - -
dateinamen:4
dateiinhalt:60
dateinamen:4
dateiinhalt:60
dateinamen:4
dateiinhalt:100
dateinamen:4
dateiinhalt:100
GET / 200 139.259 ms - -
```

What causes the code to extend the arrays while reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

The non-blocking problem is due do your `for(...)` loops. 
Changing them by : `array.forEach(function(elem, index){});`

**EDIT**

The arrays should be initialized *inside* the `index function` :

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    var dateinamen = [];
    var dateiinhalt = [];
...
```

Also, I'm not sure you need the use of EventEmitter.
Something like

`

```
fs.readdir('./data', function (err, files) {
    if (!err) {
        files.forEach(function(file){
            var buf = fs.readFileSync('./data/'+file, "utf8");
            var xml = new XML(buf);
            var list = xml.descendants("suggestion");
            var ergebnis = null;
            var obj = null;
            list.each(function(item, index){
                ergebnis = item.attribute('data').toString();
                obj = {k: file,    v: ergebnis};
                dateiinhalt.push(obj);
            });
        });
        console.log(dateiinhalt);
    } else {
        throw err;
    }
});
```

`
could do the job no?

(I wanted to say this as a comment, but I'm still missing reputation)

Comment: thanks, i tested replacing the for loops, but that doesnt solved the problem.

Comment: You are initializing the arrays (dateinamen and dateiinhalt ) outisde the index function. So they stay filled from the previous call.

Comment: i tested this but that didnt solved the problem. to put the code into a separate function outside of exports.index = function(req, res) { helped. now im calling the separate function within.